# Is it safe to alias open with xdg-open

Tags: linux, command-line, command-line-interface

I want to setup an alias `alias open=xdg-open` this whould replace the normal linux `open` command which in turn itself is a symlink to `openvt`.

I've running a debian wheezy installation with a bash shell. Does Anybody see there possible problems if I do so?

Comment: I've had it aliased for several years and never had any problems. :-)

Comment: For your interest, [Debian 11 released with this change](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html): " A new `open` command is available as a convenience alias to `xdg-open` (by default) or `run-mailcap`, managed by the `update-alternatives(1)` system. It is intended for interactive use at the command line, to open files with their default application, which can be a graphical program when available."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is. Once you alias it, it's valid only for your user.

You cold also add it inside `~/.bashrc`, so it will be available only for your user and only for the current shell session (aliasing itself again every time you start a new session).

In some distro, `.bashrc` loads a file called `.bash_aliases` for every session. You could also add your alias there.

Comment: Be careful not put it in single quotes, as `alias open='xdg-open'`may result in errors, e.g.: `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console` while `alias open=xdg-open` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

`alias` is simply a text replacement for the original(like preprocessor in C).

It's valid only in the current shell where it was created it unless you add it to `.rc` file or `.profile`. Once you exit, the alias is no longer there and as such I don't see why it would cause any problem.

Comment: There's a typo. The file is `.profile`. I cannot edit it since it's a one letter edit. ;)

Answer (score 2):

On some systems, the `open` command actually refers to the `run-mailcap` command. By default, running `open` is the same as running `run-mailcap`. Generally, it is safe to override `open` with a Bash alias, since that only affects the current shell session, and not Bash scripts within that session. Put this in your `.bashrc`:

```
alias open='xdg-open'
```

Debian 11 and related distros (such as Ubuntu 21.10 or later) use the `update-alternatives` system to manage the `open` command. So, if you want, you can configure the `open` command system-wide to refer to `xdg-open`, like this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/open open /usr/bin/xdg-open 50
sudo update-alternatives --config open
```